# How can I display a CBOR Web Token encoded token in a legible manner?

Tags: qr-code, cbor

I am trying to make the content of the QR code from the corona vaccination legible.
Found the following page. I just don't quite understand how I can read the scanned string.

[Link / Certification API](https://github.com/Digitaler-Impfnachweis/certification-apis/tree/master/examples)

String: `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`

Apparently this string is encoded by CBOR Web Token. Does anyone know how I can decode it with e.g. Java or PHP?

Answer (score 5):

1. [base45_decode()](https://github.com/baumann-at/base45-php)
2. [zlib_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zlib-decode.php)
3. [CBOR_decode()](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/cbor-php) to headers1, headers2, cbor_data, signature
4. CBOR_decode() cbor_data to greenpassdata
5. JSON stringify greenpassdata to a greenpass_json

Comment: Any similar chain for browser-javascript? I got it for steps 1 and 2, but can't find anything for 3 and 4.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to david's answer, if you also want to verify the signature, look up the [signing certificate](https://github.com/Digitaler-Impfnachweis/covpass-ios/blob/main/Certificates/PROD_RKI/CA/dsc.json) by its `kid`, which is `headers2[4]` in base64, and call

```
require("cose-js").sign.verify(
  <result from step 2>,
  <public key of signing certificate>
)
```

(that's Node.js, but there may be Java or PHP equivalents).

Comment: alternatives without node.js?

Answer (score 3):

Using a [base45](https://github.com/mhauri/base45) decoder:

```
composer require mhauri/base45
```

You can decode the string:

```
$base45 = new \Mhauri\Base45();
$decoded = $base45->decode(preg_replace("/^[^\:]+:/", "", $encoded));
```

Note that we're ignoring the first few characters `HC1:`, they are the Health Certificate version (1) and are not part of the base45 encoded string. You now have a zLib compressed string.

You can then using the inbuilt [`zilb_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zlib-decode.php) method to decompress the string:

```
$decompressed = zlib_decode($decoded);
```

Now we have the actual CBOR Web Token string. The next step would be to parse that string into an array. The trouble is that I have only found two open source PHP CBOR packages, neither of which are suitable for the task.

The [`2tvenom/cborencode`](https://github.com/2tvenom/CBOREncode) package doesn't support tags (yet). And [`spomky-labs/cbor-php`](https://github.com/spomky-labs/cbor-php) doesn't seem to understand the string at all, although it's such a complex package, maybe I am doing something wrong.

I'm sure there must be a way, I just haven't found it yet. For now, I'm using https://ehealth.vyncke.org/index.php to learn more about CBOR. If you figure out a way, please share!

Comment: spomky-labs/cbor-php is perfectly suitable for that. Please refer to https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/cbor-php/issues/32